# Win10 Default Apps query - where are the selections presented defined?

Tags: firefox, browser

I'm running the current version of Win10 Pro with all available updates.

I had a problem where the machine hung and I needed to power cycle.  When it came back, I discovered a quirk.

I use Firefox as my default browser, and had it set as default.  Suddenly, I invoke the current Firefox version, and it comes up and says "Firefox is not your default browser.  Do you want to make it the default?".  When I say I do, I am taken to the Settings Default apps page where there are four Firefox icons.

I know why - I maintain multiple Firefox versions using multiple profiles, and have an older Firefox ESR release, current Firefox, Firefox Developer Edition, and Firefox Nightly installed.  I want the current release version as Windows idea of the default.

Regardless of which of the ones listed I check, Firefox still doesn't think it's the default browser.  What I am trying to discover is just what each of the icons presented in Settings actually points to.  Can someone point me to where this stuff is defined?  I assume it's a registry entry, but have no idea which.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start, Settings, Apps, Default Apps, then scroll down to the Defaults by Apps link and click on that . Go down to Firefox and click on Manage. Then set Firefox that you want in the Protocol section.

It may be easier to uninstall all Firefox, restart, install the latest one, make sure it is Default and working. Then install the other versions.

Comment: I've tried that, and still no joy.  The problem is the "Firefox I want"  There are only icons, and no way to determine what a particular icon points to.  I believe I know which icon points to the current Firefox Quantum version, but selecting that everywhere I can still has FF 71 thinking it's not the default browser. That's why I was asking just where what the various icons presented were defined, and what specific Firefox installations they pointed to.  I also don't use default profile locations, which may be confusing matters.  Worst case I will install and reinstall.  Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps check Programs and Features (Control Panel) to ensure all Firefox instances are gone

Comment: I'll do that check if I do uninstall/reinstall. I don't use the default install or profile locations.  I know where everything actually lives.  I just don't know which icon points to which installation.